# Where does %rip register point?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, att, program-counter

I'm studying assembly, and I wonder where does %rip point when a instruction is being executed. For example,

```
0x123456       call  %eip+0x210
0x123459       movl  %eax, %edx
```

In this code, when assembler reaches 0x123456, the address 0x123456 will be stored at %rip register. And then when it executes the *call* intsruction, I'm not sure about the exact position to jump. Will it jumps to 0x123456 + 0x210? Or 0x123459 + 0x210?

Comment: In machine code the answer is clear. In assembly it's not, because the assembler can translate the offset. Which do you mean?

Comment: @harold : What is the meaning of "the assembler can translate the offset"?

Comment: An assembler may use the convention that "if you refer to the current address, it means the address of the current instruction", it's separate from how machine code works because the assembler can easily adjust the offset to translate between its convention and how the machine code works

Comment: For `e8 00 00 00 00` it is unambiguous that it's a call to the address *after* the call instruction

Comment: Assembling with GAS: ```Error: junk `+0x210' after register``` in 64-bit mode, or ```Error: bad register name `%eip+0x210'``` in 32-bit mode.  **This isn't real syntax**, but hopefully the `+0x210` is the offset encoded into the machine code, i.e. relative to the *end* of the `call` instruction.  Also, given the use of `%eip`, this code is probably being disassembled as 32-bit mode.  I guess you can assume it will run in compat mode under a 64-bit kernel and still talk about RIP if you want, even though RIP-relative addressing modes aren't available only relative jumps.